# How do i read all the links present in a file using open function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

```
imagelist=[]
with open("imagelink.txt") as url:
    for url2 in url:
        if url2.strip():
            raw_data= urllib.request.urlopen(url2.strip()).read()
            im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=raw_data)
            result = maintext.image_create(0.0, image=im)
            imagelist.append(im) # save a reference of the image
```

EDIT

Ok so i copied/followed the code exactly but when i run the images are not seen the in the text widget just white screen is visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the first image in the text widget is shown because you used same variable for all instances of `PhotoImage()`, so the previous loaded images will be garbage collected.

You need to save a reference for all the instances of image:

```py
imagelist = []  # list to store references of image
with open("imagelink.txt") as url:
    for url2 in url:
        if url2.strip():
            raw_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url2.strip()).read()
            im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=raw_data)
            result = maintext.image_create(0.0, image=im)
            imagelist.append(im) # save a reference of the image
```

Note that the result of `maintext.image_create(...)` is not a tkinter widget, so you cannot call `.pack()` on it.

Comment: i tried this but the images are not visible only white screen is visible why is it?

Comment: Are the URLs valid image URL?  Any error shown in the console? It works fine with my sample `imagelink.txt`.

Comment: yes my links are valid when i open the link in the browser it works perfectly and there is no error shown in my console aswell

Comment: i have seen that you haven't used readline in the code to read the content in the file?

Comment: It is because `url` is an iteratable object.  Also did you modify your code same as mine?  Maybe you update your question with the new code changes.

Comment: As I said, you need to post the updated code, otherwise I can't help.

Comment: i posted the code now please help me with this

Comment: Did your updated code inside a function?

Comment: yes the code is inside a function which is a command to a button

Comment: Then you need to put `imagelist = []` outside of the function, i.e. in main code block.  Or change `imagelist` to `maintext.imagelist`.

Comment: yess its working thank you very much thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, you are skipping the first line. You might want to include it, like so:

```
with open("imagelink.txt") as url:
    for url2 in url.readlines():
        # do stuff
```

else :

```
with open("imagelink.txt") as url:
    line = url.readline()
    while line:
        # do stuff
        line = url.readline()
```

Then, you might need to check if your line is or has one or several url strings. You could use a `regular expression` for that.

```
import re
# Example of regex pattern matching urls. You can find more defined ones, if you need.
url_pattern = r"http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+"

with open("imagelink.txt") as url:
    line = url.readline()
    while line:
        for link in re.findall(url_pattern, line):
             u = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
             # do other stuff
        line = url.readline()
```

The second inner `for loop` insures you don't try to do anything with something that is not an url. If no url was found, the inner loop will break and pass to the next line.

Thanks to @acw1668 for the correction on `url.read_line` vs `url.readlines`.

Comment: I think `for url2 in url.readline()` should be either `for url2 in url` or `for url2 in url.readlines()` instead.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @Whole Brain nope after following this nothing happened and also i think you did not get my problem?

Comment: I answered the question highlighted in the title. If you still have an issue, then it is with the tkinter image part, which is a different question.

Comment: @WholeBrain my problem here is that its not reading all the links present in the text file its just reading 1st line and giving the results

Comment: That's the problem I just addressed. You should get all urls present in the text file, unless urls are splitted between several lines.